# Rstudio Help Viewer Rendering Issue

Tags: rstudio

I'm having this strange issue with Rstudio where unstyled text in the help viewer pane seems to render with a white font color.

I'm not sure if anyone else has experienced this and has any suggestions on how to fix it. I've restarted Rstudio a few times and installed the latest version, 1.1.453.

My R Version is 3.4.1.

For some reason if I pop the window out, the problem disappears.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer on the Rstudio community here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-1-1-help-links-bug/2232)

I had to change my theme. For reference, I had been using the pre-packaged theme Dracula, and swapped it out for Cobalt and now all of my links are blue again...

What a relief, that was miserable for little a while there.